# How to get the data stored in the ledger via TxnID in fabric-sdk-go?

Tags: go, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-go

I have stored a data let's say `ABC` in the Ledger and got `X123` as a Transaction hash in response. Now, I want to use this transaction hash `X123` to fetch the data `ABC` from the ledger. I found [this package](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/blob/v1.0.0-alpha5/pkg/client/ledger/ledger.go) which provides the method `QueryTransaction(txn_hash)` and states that `QueryTransaction queries the ledger for processed transaction by transaction ID`

My questions are:

1. Is this a correct method to do the above operation? If no, Please suggest some methods.
2. If yes, Do I have to use some parsing logic to correctly format it?
3. Do we have parsing logic or decoder in `go-sdk` like `BlockDecoder` is there in `node-sdk`?

the screenshot of the response that I'm getting using this method.

[image: QueryTransaction response]

Answer (score 1):

Download the fabric sample from `https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples`

Q1: In the Balance Transfer project. At the bottom of the `app.js`, all methods are already implemented.

1. Query Get Block by BlockNumber
2. Query Get Transaction by Transaction ID
3. Query Get Block by Hash
4. The query for Channel Information
5. The query for Channel instantiated chaincodes
6. Query to fetch all Installed/instantiated chaincodes
7. Query to fetch channels

All the functions are defined in `Query.js`, please refer to this project.

Q2: All requested data will be coming as JSON, so no need to parse.

Q3: Even fF you want to decode any .pb file, you a use configtxlator tool, Please make sure that you have configtxlater binary available. For decoding .pb file use following command
For Envelope

> configtxlator proto_decode --input your_file.pb --type common.Envelope

For Block file

> configtxlator proto_decode --input config_block.pb --type common.Block | jq .data.data[0].payload.data.config > config.json